# Qt SIZE_MAX and UINT32_C errors? How do I fix this?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, header-files, emscripten

I am running Qt 9.0.0 with Qt 6.5.0 and the latest emscripten build. I can build my project just fine with MSVC but I cannot get it to build into web assembly.

I seem to have gotten so close but now I have hit the following errors in the header and cpp files.

In the two headers files I have I get these errors:

```
backend.h
#include <QObject> In included file: Unsupported platform (unknown value for SIZE_MAX)
#include "clientstuff.h" no error

clientstuff.h
#include <QString> In included file: Unsupported platform (unknown value for SIZE_MAX)
#include <QTcpSocket> In included file: use of undeclared identifier 'UINT32_C'
#include <QDataStream> no error
#include <QTimer> no error
```

In my three cpp files I have the following errors:

```
backend.cpp
#include "backend.h" In included file: Unsupported platform (unknown value for SIZE_MAX)

clientstuff.cpp
#include "clientstuff.h" In included file: Unsupported platform (unknown value for 
SIZE_MAX)
#include <QTcpSocket> no error
#include <QThread> In included file: Use of undeclared identifier 'UINT16_C'

main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication> In included file: Unsupported platform (unknown value for 
SIZE_MAX)
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine> no error
#include "backend.h" no error
```

I have tried all sorts of stuff to fix this. I went into the CMakeList.txt and added in the packages as required components. Currently my required components are as follows.

```
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Quick VirtualKeyboard Multimedia Network 
WebChannel)

target_link_libraries(appUi PUBLIC
Qt6::Quick
Qt6::Core
Qt6::Gui
Qt6::Qml
Qt6::VirtualKeyboard
Qt6::Network
Qt6::Multimedia
)
```

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it. The problem was not what I expected it to be.

Somehow I had upgraded emscripten to 3.1.35 while I was tinkering with it, it was supposed to be 3.1.25.

Once I reverted back to 3.1.25 these errors went away. Then I had a new error where the build kept failing because "OneDrive - Example" has spaces in the file name which is annoying so I have finally removed that.

The build just finished running and the code deployed but failed in the web browser so I have more work to do now.